# Button not clicking in Portrait Mode

Tags: android

I have a button to which I attach an onClickListener via code. I have to to this through code because it's in a fragment.

The listener works fine when in landscape mode, but when it's in portrait it doesn't. There's no "click" sound even.

In my xml file, I set the initial visibility of the button to invisible and then make it visible later when the user clicks a radio button in the same Viewgroup as the button. The onclicklisteners of the radiobuttons are working just fine in both portrait and landscape mode.

Now if I remove the "android:visibility="invisible" code in xml, the onclickstener works fine in portrait mode! But of course I need it invisible till the user clicks a radiobutton otherwise the UI doesn't make sense. Very weird indeed.

Here's my code:

```
private void setOnClickForSaveButton(View v) {

        Button changeFundsSave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.change_funds_save);
        changeFundsSave.setOnClickListener(saveListener);

    }

Button.OnClickListener saveListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Get the rootview
            View rootView = v.getRootView();

            EditText changeFundsEdit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_funds_edit);

            if(changeFundsEdit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle( "" )
                .setMessage( "Enter the number of units" )
                .setPositiveButton( "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    }
                })
                .show();
                return;


            }


        }
    };


    private void setOnClicksForRadioButtons(View v) {

        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.add_units);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.remove_units);
        RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.set_units);

        rb1.setOnClickListener(addRemoveSetButtonListener);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(addRemoveSetButtonListener);
        rb3.setOnClickListener(addRemoveSetButtonListener);

    }





    OnClickListener addRemoveSetButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Since we only have the radiobutton view, we need to get the parent
            View rootView = v.getRootView();

            //Make the controls visible
            TextView changeFundsText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_funds_text);
            EditText changeFundsEdit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_funds_edit);
            Button changeFundsSave = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_funds_save);

            changeFundsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changeFundsEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changeFundsSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    };


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem! In portrait mode, like everyone else I load one fragment in a separate activity. Out of habit I was calling setContentView(something) before loading the fragment! So ultimately the two layouts were overlapping each other and the visible and invisible buttons were overlapping each other and things must have gotten messed up. Damn, I'm not sure if I like the concept of fragments at all. My first time using them. But maybe I just need to learn how to wire them up properly before I get used to them :) Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that

1) do you findViewById again for the view you passed in setOnClickForSaveButton? since the old view will be destroyed and a view will be created when you change screen orientation
2) do you have multiple ids for R.id.change_funds_save
3) add a log at the first line of onclick(v) to see if it is called but goto another branch you didnt expect.

Comment: Problem solved - I was using setContentView for the activity and ALSO setting a fragment in R.id.content at the same time! Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are loading two separate xml layout files from `layout-land` and `layout-port`, there shouldn't be much difference between landscape mode and portrait mode. That being said, I'm going to take a wild guess and say that your app is probably not working correctly due to configuration changes. Let me know if this is actually true... i.e. does your app work at first, but stops working when you rotate the screen?

If this is true, you should look into how the Activity lifecycle is affecting your views and `onClickListener`s.

Comment: Solved the problem! In portrait mode, like everyone else I load one fragment in a separate activity. Out of habit I was calling setContentView(something) before loading the fragment!

So ultimately the two layouts were overlapping each other and the visible and invisible buttons were overlapping each other and things must have gotten messed up.

Damn, I'm not sure if I like the concept of fragments at all. My first time using them. But maybe I just need to learn how to wire them up properly before I get used to them :)

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You should post this as an answer and then accept it. That way you can officially close the problem :)

Comment: Will do - as soon as I have enough rep :)